# TinyMCE Content_css is not working in Cloud version

Tags: tinymce

I am using cdn.tiny.cloud v5.
When I initialize the editor I'm using content_css

tinymce.init({
content_css: "myCssFile.css"
...
});

When I use TinyMce cloud version my css file does not affect the editor content.
When I change to TinyMCE self host version, the content_css does work.

Am I missing something?

Thank's
Zmira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use TinyMce cloud version my css file does not affect the
> editor content

If you look at the browser's Network tab I suspect you will see that (based on how you defined the path to your CSS file) that the browser is looking on the Cloud server for your CSS.

When you use a simple "path" like that you are in effect telling TinyMCE to go back to where it found TinyMCE for the CSS file but if you are pulling TinyMCE from the Cloud server that would not be a valid path for the CSS.  You likely need a more complete path.  For example:

```
content_css: "https://my.server.com/files/css/myCssFile.css"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. Changing the path solved the problem.